# GAM residuals missing in plot

Tags: r, plot, gam, mgcv

I am applying a GAM model to my data: cell abundance over time.
The model works just fine (although I am aware of a pattern in my resiudals, but this is a different issue not relevant here).
It just fails to display the partial residuals in the final plot, although i set `residuals = TRUE`. Here is my output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1MlY.png

also I used mgcv package.

Previously this code worked as I wanted, but on different data. Any ideas on why it is not working are welcome!

```
GAM_EA <- mgcv::gam(EUB_FISH ~ s(Day, by = Heatwave), data = HnH, method = "REML")
gam.check(GAM_EA) #Checking the model
mgcv::anova.gam(GAM_EA) #Retrieving the statistical results. See ?anova.gam
summary.gam(GAM_EA)
plot(GAM_EA, shift = coef(GAM_EA)[1], residuals = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See argument `by.resid` in `?plot.gam`. They way these are used in `plot.gam` would been meaningless for factor by terms unless you were to subset the partial residuals and plot only the residuals for observations in the specific level of the `by` factor.

Comment: Yes, in fact i only provided the output plot for one of my two subsets. The main idea is to see whether both models differ based on this factor, but for this it would be good to see how well each smooth fits the respective residuals.
Does this make it clearer?

Comment: You *can't* do this with `plot.gam` unless you set `by.resid = TRUE` but that won't be right as it doesn't subset. Looking to see how well a smooth fits the respective residuals doesn't make sense - the residuals are derived from the smooth. You should be looking to see if the partial residuals are randomly and even spread about the smooth. If you want to see these residuals on a model with factor by smooths, you could try my gratia package (on CRAN) and then do `draw(GAM_EA, residuals = TRUE)`, which does subset the residuals for the respective factor by smooth